# FileObserver not registering CREATE in onEvent

Tags: android, file, fileobserver

I have a pretty simple implementation of FileObserver:

```
        observer = new FileObserver(rootPath+"Pictures") {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            //event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;
            Log.d("home","event: "+event);
            if (event == FileObserver.CREATE) {
                Toast.makeText(cont, "File created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
```

it's not registering the `FileObserver.CREATE constant (256)`.  My log is showing `several 1's (Access), a few 16's (close_nowrite) and a few 32's (open) when I create a file but never a 256`.

I've tried on two devices **(Samsung Galaxy S7 Active and One Plus Two)**

anything I need to do differently here?

Comment: That you can display a Toast there!? I had to put it in runInUIThread(). I advise you to put an else statement there and show a toast with event and path. You could miss some events wich you did not expect. I put the observer on DCIM/Camera and get very many toasts after taking a picture. Including "File created". `path is a relative path: only the file name.`

Comment: well that's not the issue.  I've also put a Log.d() statement inside my if and it never gets called.  I'm logging every event also and never see the event code for CREATE.

Comment: Could you try for DCIM/Camera too? `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()+ "/Camera" ) `

Comment: If you create a file then how? Your own app or how?

Comment: DCIM doesn't work either.  I'm not going to be creating files in my app directly.  I need to listen for files being added to the directory by a different process.

Comment: `DCIM ` .I ment DCIM/Camera and then take pictures.

Comment: ya did that.  still not registering CREATE

Comment: Maybe try different device? Other OS version? The CREATE is for a ...jpg.tmp file as first event. Is 128 a rename?

Comment: Toast.makeText can work in main UI thread only,  it should not be used here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact answer, but I know that there are more event codes than are listed in the doc and/or some of them are kind of combinations, especially when you are watching directories and subdirectories.

What you can do is, if you are interested in CREATE events, instead of asking

```
if (event == FileObserver.CREATE) { /* do something */ }
```

try asking if it contains CREATE flag:

```
if ((event & FileObserver.CREATE) == FileObserver.CREATE) { /* do something */}
```

In particular, though this is probably not in your case, when creating a directory, an ISDIR flag is added to the CREATE event.

Hope that helps someone. [Here is a nice description](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) of the system Android's FileObserver is based on.

Comment: What if the file doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 0):

**#Try this one, hope it will work for you. I already tested it.**

```
observer = new FileObserver(rootPath+"Pictures", FileObserver.CREATE) {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            //event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;
            Log.d("home","event: "+event);
            Toast.makeText(cont, "File created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
```

Make sure that rootPath + "Pictures" is the proper file path.